# Iterating through dimensions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array

How do I simplify these commands to a single line in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)?

```
medoidContainer(:, i, 1) = squeeze(reshape(container(:, :, 1),1, y * x));
medoidContainer(:, i ,2) = squeeze(reshape(container(:, :, 2),1, y * x));
medoidContainer(:, i ,3) = squeeze(reshape(container(:, :, 3),1, y * x));
```

With them, I reshape an [RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) image to a matrix of a single line (for each color). But how can I do this without having to iterate through each dimension?

---

*I have tried:*

```
medoidContainer(:, i ,1:3) = squeeze(reshape(container(:, :, 1:3),1, y * x));
```

*But that doesn't work.*

Comment: It's not quite clear what the aim is here.  Are you trying to turn an `M x N x 3` array into an `(M*N) x 3` array?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, yes (and the variable i is part of the loop in which this is used, and iterates through a list of images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to convert an `M x N x 3` array into an `(M*N) x 3` array.  You can do this as follows:

```
a = reshape(container, [M*N 3]);
```

To assign it into your "container", I think you need this:

```
medoidContainer(:,i,:) = a;
```

Comment: That did it! I used it as `medoidContainer(:, i, :) = reshape(container, [y*x 3]);`, works like a charm. Thanks!